# Чтения слов из файла

Tags: c++, файлы

Задание следующие: пользователь вводит адрес директории и ключевое слово, моя задача найти все текстовые файлы в этой директории, которые содержат это ключевое слово.
Вот мой код:

```
void ShowListFile(string p,string word)
{
    for (auto i = fs::directory_iterator(p); i != fs::directory_iterator(); i++)
    {
        if (!fs::is_directory(i->path())) 
        {
            if (i->path().extension() == ".txt")
            {
                string find;
                find = p + "\\";
                find += i->path().filename().string();
                ifstream fin(find);
                cout << find << endl;
                int l;
                string wr;
                string str1;
                string str2;
                str2 = word;
                while (getline(fin, wr))
                {
                    for (int l = 0; l <= wr.length(); l++)
                        if (wr[l] != ' ' && l != wr.length())
                            str1 = str1 + wr[l];
                        else if (wr[l] == ' ' || l == wr.length())
                        {
                            if(str1 == str2)
                            {
                                cout << i->path().filename().string() << "Есть слово" << endl;
                                fin.close();
                                continue;
                            }
                            str1 = "";
                        }
                }

                fin.close();
                //cout << i->path().filename().string() << endl;
            }

        }
        else
            continue;
    }
}
```

Т.е в чем суть, в p передается путь,а word это ключевое слово. Но почему-то он не находит нужные текстовые файлы

Comment: Ну, а дебажить вы пробовали? Например, печатайте слова, когда достаете их из файла. Убедитесь, что слова правильные.

Comment: Хорошая идея! Сейчас попробую

Comment: Отлично! Теперь проблема следующая, сделал, так чтобы выводило все слова из файлов выводит правильно ( из английских букв и русских) Но когда я ищу слово из английских букв оно его находит, а если из русских то нет, даже если оно там есть

Comment: Разберитесь с кодировками: 1. В какой кодировке файлы? 2. В какой кодировке исходное слово? (Второе зависит от того от куда вы его берете: строковой литерал, ввод из консоли, или файл?)

Comment: Кстати, в чем смысл делать `l <= wr.length()` вместо `<` если потом все равно проверяете `l != wr.length()`?

Comment: l <= wr.length() - согласен, все дело в не опытности)) кодировка файлов ANSI, слово вводится из консоли

Comment: Т.е я беру слово с клавиатуры, записываю его в string потом передаю в void

Comment: ANSI - это скорее всего Windows-1251. Раз из консоли - то это скорее всего CP866. Можно вручную преобразовать одно в другое. Либо можно сохранить файл в CP866. Еще есть `SetConsoleCP` в `<windows.h>`; про нее не уверен, но тоже может сработать.

Comment: А как преобразовать одно в другое? Менять кодировку консоли не вариант, весь мой русский текст поплыл

Comment: А мне кажется - вполне вариант. Раз поплыл - надо поиграть с `SetConsoleOutputCP` и с кодировкой файла с исходным кодом. Он скорее всего в UTF8, попробуйте сохранить как CP866 или Windows-1251.

Comment: *"А как преобразовать одно в другое"* Нагуглить обе кодировки. Выяснить, какие числа соответствуют кириллице в обоих.

Comment: Кодировка файла только ANSI, в других случаях он просто напросто плывет